# How can I convert the following disassembly code to pseudo code or C code?

Tags: disassembly, x86, c

I used IDA pro to get the following disassembly code. I am having difficulty converting it into the equivalent c code.

```
mov dword ptr [ebp-8], 1
mov dword ptr [ebp-4], 0
loc_401014:
 cmp dword ptr [ebp-4], 4
 jge short loc_40102E
 mov eax, [ebp-8]
 add eax, [ebp-4]
 mov [ebp-8], eax
 mov ecx, [ebp-4]
 add ecx, 1
 mov [ebp-4], ecx
 jmp short loc_401014
loc_40102E:
```

Answer (score 2):

This C code compiles to the equivalent of your assembly code:

```
void f() {
    int b = 1;
    for (int a = 0; a<4; ++a) {
        b = b + a;
    }
    // disassembly finishes here but maybe there's something like below
    // return b;
}
```

The output on [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Jkm5Pq) switches `[ebp-8]` and `[ebp-4]` and uses `eax` rather than `ecx` to increment the loop variable but it looks equivalent to what you wanted.

Comment: Please copy the code here when you write answers so that the answer is still relevant even when godbolt is down.

Comment: thank you. @booto can you give me some tips as to how can I convert this? Is there any tool?

Comment: [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/) is pretty good - you can write C/C++ in the left pane and see the resulting assembly in the right. You can change the target compiler/architecture or the flags being passed to the compiler, or add multiple panes with other compilers. Are you familar with x86? The [Intel Software Developer Manuals](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) are a verbose reference, but you can probably find briefer summaries. I'm not familiar with tools that will automatically do the conversion for you.